# CCAvenue Payment Gateway Integration in Android apps?

Tags: android, payment-processing, ccavenue

I want to do **CCAvenue** Payment Gateway Integration in Android apps. I googled but I didn't find any APIs/SDK for Android.
 Is there any APIs/SDK available for Android/Java to do **CCAvenue** integration?

Comment: downvoter plz do your comments.. thnks

Comment: i am also looking for same..!

Comment: This question was probably downvoted because it is not a programming question. "I'm looking for...." is not considered an acceptable question at Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JohnConde .. please tell me where to ask! as its very urgent for me.. Thanks

Comment: @NiravDangi : Did you get the CCavenue developer api for Android ???

Comment: You need to register for their service. after validation of required documents they provide you the android integration api and guide to set up payment gateway.